# GDPR compliance in Amazon AWS

Tags: aws, gdpr

Anybody has a nice checklist/todo list to achieve GDPR compliance in Amazon AWS environments? Want to use dev-sec.io checklists, OWASP for web app, AWS Trusted Advisor. Anything else to include/consider? How to tackle GDPR in AWS environments?

Was also thinking to start by checking the ISO 27000 audit points and then add GDPR requirements towards of IT.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/gdpr-center/

Comment: Thanks. Yea, I know this resource. Was just wondering if anybody has some high level checklist/process, processes description and what tools can be used for each areas to comply. Answer could be also general and high level. I saw Amazon AWS GDPR Webinar, and they based it on AWS CloudTrail, AWS IAM and Chef Automate.

Comment: this is not really an answer but you might need to provide reassurance regarding the Cloud Act vs GDPR if you are using one of AWS Cloud based in Europe.
And if it is in the UK, you will likely be asked to move your data to Continental Europe before Marsh.